# Can't select Reporting Services in Management Studio?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008r2-express

I've installed Sql Server 2008 R2 Express Advanced SP1 for my client including Reporting Services.

I've configured the Reporting Services but when opening Management Studio I can't open the Reporting Services..

Is this a missing feature in Expres or is there something wrong?

[image: Wot?]

Sql Server version 10.50.2500.0 on Windows SBS 2011 standard.

Comment: Perhaps you need [Management Studio Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1842)?

Comment: Jeroen, I've mentioned Advanced in the question

Comment: Ah, apologies, didn't read correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Management Studio Express to manage Reporting Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Damn shame if you ask me.. But then again it's free.